# ResultCode and RequestCode are not working

Tags: android

I called from `MainActivity` to `InfomationActivity` using a requestcode. However when returning `MainActivity`, it inactivity. What is the problem here?

In `MainActivity`, call `InfomationActivity` using a requestcode:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InfomationActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

In `InfomationActivity`, return a resultcode:

```
        if(btnAlarmInfo.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            //run
            Log.d("abc", note.getTitle() + "/" + note.getNote() + "/" + note.getDateTime() + "/" + note.getColorBackground());
            Log.d("abc", Integer.toString(images.size()));
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            intent.putExtra("title", note.getTitle());
            intent.putExtra("note", note.getNote());
            intent.putExtra("time", note.getDateTime());
            intent.putExtra("color", note.getColorBackground());
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("image", images);
            setResult(3, intent);
            finish();
        }else{
            //run
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            intent.putExtra("title", note.getTitle());
            intent.putExtra("note", note.getNote());
            intent.putExtra("time", note.getDateTime());
            intent.putExtra("color", note.getColorBackground());
            intent.putExtra("day", note.getDayAlarm());
            intent.putExtra("hour", note.getHourAlarm());
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("image", images);
            setResult(4, intent);
            finish();
        }
```

And when `MainActivity` return:

```
if(requestCode == 100){
        if(resultCode == 3){
            //not run ????????
            Log.d("abc", "it's me");
            String title = data.getExtras().getString("title");
            String note = data.getExtras().getString("note");
            String time = data.getExtras().getString("time");
            String color = data.getExtras().getString("color");
            ArrayList<Image> image = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra("image");
            Log.d("abc", Integer.toString(image.size()));
            ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
            for(int i = 0; i < image.size(); i++){
                bitmaps.add(image.get(i).getImage());
            }
            Note note1 = new Note(title, note, false, time, color, "", "", bitmaps);
            this.addNote(note1);
        }else if(resultCode == 4){
            //run
            String title = data.getExtras().getString("title");
            String note = data.getExtras().getString("note");
            String time = data.getExtras().getString("time");
            String color = data.getExtras().getString("color");
            String day = data.getExtras().getString("day");
            String hour = data.getExtras().getString("hour");
            ArrayList<Image> image = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra("image");
            ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
            for(int i = 0; i < image.size(); i++){
                bitmaps.add(image.get(i).getImage());
            }
            Note note1 = new Note(title, note, true, time, color, day, hour, bitmaps);
            this.addNote(note1);
        }
    }
```

In logcat, i see it not run when resultcode = 3. Why when resultcode = 3, it does not run?

Comment: Integer values are not applicable for this result, it may behave abnormal, so I recommend you to use RESULT_OK only and set one parameter in it with 3 or 4 as int , and main thing is you don't need to put all values in if-else loop so try it

Comment: if there are 2 cases handled, it will ok, but i want more cases ???

Comment: You can add any number of cases not an issue

Comment: what should i do, can you give me an example

Comment: You don't have to pass int value like 3,4 in set result you have to pass only RESULT_OK and pass one more variable in data to check more cases

Comment: Are you able to do this your you need me to post answer ?

Comment: Oh, you do not need to do so! i just need idea :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result code is supposed to be set using one of the predefined values `RESULT_OK`, `RESULT_CANCELLED`, or `RESULT_FIRST_USER` in the activity which is started.

Setting values like 3 and 4 do not necessarily have a defined behavior here; if they have some meaning for you (and are not just random), then pass them back as another extra on the Intent. Use `RESULT_OK` in their place.

Also, for the Intent you use to pass back the result, I would recommend creating a new one using `new Intent()` rather than reusing the one that was used to start the activity (which is what `getIntent()` gives you).

In any case, I would recommend that you review [this section of the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities), which deals with starting activities and getting results.

Comment: I need 4 handle cases returned, what should I do?

Comment: @KhanhDoan, if there are 4 different cases you need handled, then I would suggest that you set the result code as RESULT_OK, and then pass the int specifying which use case it is in your return Intent. Then in your calling activity you check the return intent to see which of the 4 cases it was.